# Split MySQL String to two fields

Tags: mysql, string, split

In short, I have a PHP form that asks for employee id, email and password to add the user to the DB which works fine.

The table in the DB also has Firstname and Lastname fields.

Because the powers that be feel asking for fname and lname in the form is a step too far, I wanted to split the employee id so that it populated at least the fname. Last name we're not overly bothered about as it isn't unique anyway.

In short, each employee id is made up of the same format, ie, first name followed by a number (ie John12345, Mark67890 (5 digits per employee id after the firstname)). I would like to insert into the DB the employee id, and whilst it's doing that, Split out at the first number (or last letter) and populate the firstname (the rest of the string split can be purged as long as the full employee id is inserted into the employee_id).

I've read that a split function is not available in MySQL so I'm trying to figure out the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Left and Right functions as follow:

```
SET @employee = 'Employee12345';
SELECT RIGHT(@employee ,5), LEFT(@employee, LENGTH(@employee)-5);
```

Because employee number code is a 5 digit number, then you could use this code.
If you wanna insert into another table, you must use INSERT INTO SELECT Statement as Follow:

```
Insert into _newtable Select RIGHT(_employee ,5), LEFT(_employee, LENGTH(_employee)-5) FROM _oldtable;
```

Where _employee is your oldtable field.

Comment: ah ok, I see. The users are already in a table, so all I really want to do is run the query to split what is there into another column, rather than a new table, and the perfect world would be the submit from the PHP form would do the magic.

Answer (score 0):

I used a much better method than the proposed solution here:

I used php explode on the email field (which is mandated as firstname.lastinitial

```
$email = "myemail@someemail.com";
$firstname = explode(".", $email)[0];
$lastname = explode("@", explode(".", $email)[1])[0];
$username = $firstname . " " . $lastname;
```